# Data comparison between two tables in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement where I have two tables `tbl_bb` and `tbl_rr` and data in them like this:

**tbl_bb**:

```
isin    agency  rating  date
----------------------------------
142356  MDA     A       2010-01-20
142356  MDA     AA      2012-05-14
142356  MDA     BB      2013-07-04
```

**tbl_rr**:

```
isin    agency  rr_rating   rr_date
------------------------------------
142356  MDA     A         2010-01-15
142356  MDA     AA+       2009-05-30
142356  MDA     BBB       2013-07-04
```

Now, requirement is I have to pick each and every record from tbl_bb and loop through the data in tbl_rr based on joining of isin and agency and the condition for looping is consider date from tbl_bb and check **every date** from `tbl_rr` and pick the closest date to that of `tbl_bb` date and other condition is `rr_date(tbl_rr) <= date (tbl_bb)`

**Output:**

```
isin    agency  rating  date     rr_rating  rr_date
-------------------------------------------------------
142356  MDA       A     2010-01-20    A     2010-01-15
142356  MDA       AA    2012-05-14    AA+   2010-01-15
142356  MDA       BB    2013-07-04    BBB   2013-07-04
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Rather than asking for a full solution from us; do you have any examples that you have tried. We can then aid you in correcting any mistakes etc.

Comment: @jamesakadamingo I have tried using cursor and got an output I was trying to find out other possible ways of doing it so.

Comment: Where does the `rr_rating` of `AAA` and `BB+` come from in your output as it's not in either table?

Comment: @Tanner Sorry I have updated the output fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using [`APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get the closest 1 record from `tbl_rr`:

```
SELECT  bb.isin,
        bb.agency,
        bb.rating,
        bb.date,
        rr.rr_rating, 
        rr.rr_date
FROM    tbl_bb AS bb
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 rr.rr_rating, rr.rr_date
            FROM    tbl_rr AS rr
            WHERE   rr.isin = bb.isin
            AND     rr.agency = bb.agency
            AND     rr.rr_date <= bb.date
            ORDER BY rr.rr_date DESC
        ) AS rr;
```

---

**FULL WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
-- SAMPLE DATA
WITH tbl_bb AS
(   SELECT  isin, agency, rating, date
    FROM    (VALUES
                (142356,'MDA','A','2010-01-20'),
                (142356,'MDA','AA','2012-05-14'),
                (142356,'MDA','BB','2013-07-04')
            ) AS bb(isin, agency, rating, date)
), tbl_rr AS
(   SELECT  isin, agency, rr_rating, rr_date
    FROM    (VALUES
                (142356,'MDA','A','2010-01-15'),
                (142356,'MDA','AA+','2012-05-30'),
                (142356,'MDA','BBB','2013-07-04')
            ) AS rr (isin, agency, rr_rating, rr_date)
)
-- SAMPLE DATA END
SELECT  bb.isin,
        bb.agency,
        bb.rating,
        bb.date,
        rr.rr_rating, 
        rr.rr_date
FROM    tbl_bb AS bb
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 rr.rr_rating, rr.rr_date
            FROM    tbl_rr AS rr
            WHERE   rr.isin = bb.isin
            AND     rr.agency = bb.agency
            AND     rr.rr_date <= bb.date
            ORDER BY rr.rr_date DESC
        ) AS rr;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is I would join these tables as given in description, find `DATEDIFF` between two dates and then just find lowest `DATEDIFF` value for each `ISIN` and `agency`

Answer (score 0):

As per my assumption we can proceed like this if you want filter the data we can achieve like

```
C.RN - 1 = CC.RR or   C.RN - 1 > CC.RR OR C.RN - 1 < CC.RR
```

Code:

```
  declare @t table (ISIN INT,Agency varchar(10),Rating varchar(5),dated date)
    insert into @t (ISIN,Agency,Rating,dated)values (142356,'MDA','A','2010-01-20'),
    (142356,'MDA','AA','2012-05-14'),
    (142356,'MDA','BB','2013-07-04')


    declare @tt table (ISIN INT,Agency varchar(10),Rating varchar(5),dated date)
    insert into @tt (ISIN,Agency,Rating,dated)values (142356,'MDA','A','2010-01-15'),
    (142356,'MDA','AA+','2012-05-30'),
    (142356,'MDA','BBB','2013-07-04')


    ;with cte as 
    (select ISIN,
                Agency,
                Rating,
                dated,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ISIN)RN 
    from @t)
    , cte1 as 
    (select 
            ISIN,
            Agency,
            Rating,
            dated,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ISIN)RR 
    from @tt)
    select C.ISIN,C.Agency,
            C.Rating,C.dated,
            CC.Agency,CC.Rating,
            CC.dated from cte c
            INNER JOIN cte1 CC
            ON C.RN = CC.RR
```